# Restrict access for Cognito user to their resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

I have a application which uses

- Cognito User Pool/Identity Pool to authenticate user and provide access to aws Console using Custom URL

I want those user should see their resources only, I have researched a lot but can't find any solution

For S3, I tried this policy but it still says access denied. What actual value "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}" this will give.

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
    }
  ]
   }
```

For EC2, I am using below policy, If i hard code some value in  It works but I want this to be dynamic for Cognito Users. I tried placing  but not working.

```
      {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/owner": "<KeyValue>"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "NotResource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateVolume",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/owner": "<KeyValue>"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:CreateAction": [
                    "CreateVolume",
                    "RunInstances",
                    "CreateSnapshot"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DeleteTags",
            "ec2:AttachVolume",
            "ec2:DetachVolume",
            "ec2:DeleteVolume",
            "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/owner": "<KeyValue>"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:snapshot/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/owner": "<KeyValue>"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/owner": "<KeyValue>"
            }
        }
    }
          ]
          }
```

To refer my application, Here is the link for my [Code](https://github.com/sparshgoyal024/TestAWS). Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can give AWS console access for cognito users.

Comment: When you say "For S3, I tried this policy but it still says access denied", what did you do to receive that error? Was it an API call? If so, can you show us the API call?

Comment: @ArunK We can give AWS Console access using Custom Identity Broker

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Cognito User tried to open that bucket but it says access denied

Comment: Never heard about it. I will do some googling. Thanks

Comment: @ManishGoyal What do you mean by "Cognito User tried to open that bucket"? Did they do it via an AWS CLI command, an API call, or the management console? More details please.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein using Management Console

Comment: See **Policy for Console Access** in: [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)